# antd dragger upload doesn't work after adding fileList

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm having a problem with antd dragged. I'm trying to add a custom filelist to the dragged, but when I do the dragged doesn't respond anymore. The problem with the default fileList is that if a file is above size limit and doesn't get through the "beforeUpload" function it will still get add to the fileList.

https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-ant-design-demo-z5h6r

Answer (score -1):

上传文件之前的钩子，参数为上传的文件，**若返回 false 则停止上传**。支持返回一个 Promise 对象，Promise 对象 reject 时则停止上传，resolve 时开始上传（ resolve 传入 File 或 Blob 对象则上传 resolve 传入对象）。注意：IE9 不支持该方法。

(file, fileList) => boolean | Promise